# Sending POST messages using endpoint "me/messages" : code: -1, error_code: 2018012

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-app-requests, facebook-permissions

We are requesting the **pages_messaging** permission, we have submitted request multiple time and it's goes **rejected** by saying **Bot is not responding**. During testing with a test user the functionality performed seamlessly using the **"me/messages"** endpoint. However, we encountered an issue when investigating why the app reviewer wasn't receiving replies. Specifically, we identified the error as **"ERROR CODE: 2018012"** when testing from the Graph API Explorer.

In last request when web-hook App reviewer (recipient id :  XXXXX93418XXXXXX) By using this Id we get an error response Below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#-1) Unexpected internal error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": -1,
    "error_subcode": 2018012,
    "fbtrace_id": "ACzSlcFJtPOv3hATV2NmOVV"
  }
}
```

When we test with the Test User  (recipient id :  XXXXX47110XXXXXX) we got a successful response below

```
{
  "recipient_id": "XXXXX47110XXXXXX",
  "message_id": "m_G1HHOz1BbrO5bVV6..."
}
```

We are trying to get the **pages_messaging** permission for our Facebook app messenger we have implemented a bot for automate send response from **back-end** when we will receive the **web-hook**, **Expecting** while Facebook are reviewing our permission request they should get the successful response **mention in description**, but somehow they are not able to get a response from bot.